# How to add RunToLine as actionSet to my custom perspective look?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions">
<perspectiveExtension 
            targetID="ui.perspective.MyPerspective"> 
             <actionSet id="org.eclipse.debug.ui.debugActionSet"/> 
            <actionSet id="org.eclipse.debug.ui.breakpointActionSet"/> 
            <actionSet id="org.eclipse.debug.ui.launchActionSet"/>

        </perspectiveExtension> 
  </extension>
```

I have an extension point to show debug toolbar according to actionSet. But only RunToLine is not shown. Do we have any choice to show that icon in the toolbar as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `org.eclipse.debug.ui` plug-in disables this tool bar item by default:

```xml
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions">
   <perspectiveExtension targetID="*">
      <hiddenToolBarItem id="org.eclipse.debug.ui.commands.RunToLine"/>
   </perspectiveExtension>
</extension>
```

This means you have to use 'Window > Perspective > Customize Perspective' to enable the item in the 'Tool Bar Visbility' section.

Comment: There is no way to make this visible via a perspective? not manually changing this?